# selected option on angularjs dropdown

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

something is breaking my head.

I'm using angularjs on a web app and I built a table with BD results and each row has a select item witch is loaded with a model but, I don't know how to do to mark a specific option depending of result item.

My code:

```
var ctrlScope = $scope;
ctrlScope.antenas = [];

// Model to select
ctrlScope.motivos = [ 
    {id:0,descripcion:"--  Seleccion una opcion  --"},       
    {id:1,descripcion:"Corte de Luz"},
    {id:2,descripcion:"Falla de proveedor"},
    {id:3,descripcion:"Mantenimiento"},
    {id:4,descripcion:"Micro corte"},
    {id:5,descripcion:"Otro"},
    {id:6,descripcion:"Por definir"}
]


// Method to load data
call_url = app_root+'Auditoria/reporte';
    var dsd = $('#desde').val();
    var has = $('#hasta').val();

    $http.post(call_url,{desde:dsd, hasta:has})
    .then(function(resp){
        var data = resp.data
        for(var item in data){
            ctrlScope.antenas.push({
                "ip": data[item].ip,
                "nombre":data[item].nombre,
                "nodo": data[item].nodo,
                "fecha": data[item].fecha,
                "motivo": data[item].motivo
            });
        }//for
    }) //then
```

HTML:

```
<tr ng-repeat="ant in antenas">
        <td>{{ ant.ip }}</td>
        <td>{{ ant.nombre }}</td>
        <td>{{ ant.nodo }}</td>
        <td>{{ ant.fecha }}</td>
        <td>
            <select class="form-control">
                <option 
                    ng-repeat="motiv in motivos" 
                    ng-selected="{{ ant.motivo }}" 
                    value="{{ motiv.id }}">{{ motiv.descripcion }}
                </option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
```

I was trying with ng-selected but doesn't work.

Comment: what option do you want to have selected by default?

Comment: have you tried `ng-selected="ant.motivo"` instead of `ng-selected="{{ ant.motivo }}"`. And is ant.motive a variable which is true/false or null/not-null or defined/undefined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just assume that `ant.motivo` should be equal with `motiv.id`. If that is the case your option tag should look like that:

```
<option ng-repeat="motiv in motivos"
        ng-value="motiv.id"
        ng-selected="motiv.id == ant.motivo"
        ng-bind="motiv.descripcion"></option>
```

[ng-selected](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSelected) expects a expression which will be true or false. Although you can use [ng-value](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngValue) and [ng-bind](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBind).

Comment: Thanks so much, I didn't see it.

Answer (score 0):

you must use ngOptions try this

```
<select ng-model="ant.motivo"
        ng-options="motiv.id as motiv.descripcion for motiv in motivos">
</select>
```

watch here
https://plnkr.co/edit/8ZhWqRy12BwCGXxEeI5u?p=preview

Comment: Thanks, it works too and it is the best way because is specific directive for dropdown.